# Is there a way of solve failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE on actions on google

Tags: actions-on-google

when I test my function on google assistant, I got these msgs:

failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE

The agent responded empty JSON

```
{
 insertId: "1aw7l32fyd064r"  
 logName: "projects/tcl-assistant-test-e188f/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-21T05:36:52.353782775Z"  
 resource: {  labels: {   action_id: "SMART_HOME_QUERY"       project_id: "tcl-assistant-test-e188f"       version_id: ""      }  type: "assistant_action"    }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "requestId 12138341054357433632: Agent responded empty JSON."  
 timestamp: "2020-05-21T05:36:52.346943813Z"  
}
```

```
{
 insertId: "utcf5lfyossrt"  
 logName: "projects/tcl-assistant-test-e188f/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-21T05:37:24.171647717Z"  
 resource: {  labels: {   action_id: "SMART_HOME_EXECUTE"       project_id: "tcl-assistant-test-e188f"       version_id: ""      }  type: "assistant_action"    }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "requestId 2440306364591309003 failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE"  
 timestamp: "2020-05-21T05:37:24.164601512Z"  
}
```

there is no solve on internet, I tried to find the performance of those problems under different conditions.

cloud log is normal, get a query request and response the query .while you can found errors in logs viewer in google console

I create a new project credential, replace the older one. then give commands again. but still exists.

change devise or change account problem is still exists

is there anyone who can help? thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when a user tries to authenticate with your service but the authentication process fails. You'll want to check your server logs and auth process to ensure that the authentication and subsequent SYNC works as expected.